# Do not allow to change a default option using optionsResolver of Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-components

I am using the [optionsResolver](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html) component of symfony

I have the following code:

```
public function test($group, array $options = [])
{
    $this->resolver->setDefaults([
        'query' => ['group' => $group],
        'form_params' => ['user' => 'test_user'],
    ]);
    $this->resolver->setDefined('connect_timeout');
    $options = $this->resolver->resolve($options);
}
```

What I would like to do is if someone calls `test` function to throw an exception if he passes the option with key `query` but to allow him to pass the option `connect_timeout` or `form_params`.

Is this possible?